# HTTPS Post request in C

Tags: c, sockets, post, https, iot

I am working on sending data to our server from our IoT device using an HTTPS POST request, and I am wondering if there is a better way to send the payload. We are sending a good amount of data in JSON format such as voltage, state of charge, current, etc.. and I believe what I am doing is inefficient.

Here is my POST header:

```
char send_buf[] = "POST /api? HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: my-server.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-type: application/json\r\nContent-length: 15\r\n\r\n{\"key\": \"value\"}";
```

I have seen examples using snprintf to build up the string, doing something like this:

```
#define POST_TEMPLATE "POST %s? HTTP/1.1\r\n"\
        "Host: %s\r\n"\
        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"\
        "Content-type: application/json\r\n"\
        "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"\
        "%s

    int send_data_len_post = snprintf(send_buf,
                         500, /*total length should not exceed MTU size*/
                         POST_TEMPLATE, HTTP_PATH,
                         HTTP_HOST, strlen(PostString),
                         PostString);
```

where PostString is the webserver I am trying to access, but I am unable to get this to work.

It is important to note that my logic for creating and sending a socket and making a simple GET request from the server works fine, but I have been having trouble with a more complex post request. Any ideas and help would be great, thanks!

Comment: `Content-length` should be 16 in your example. I cannot see anything wrong here. If the json payload is small, it is insignificant compared to the HTTP header. On the other hand, if the payload contains much more, then some binary data can save a lot of formatting/parsing.

Comment: Can you dump the query received ?
Perhaps you server need an `Accept` header.
I recommend to do a working query using curl for example, then compare the generated query against the working curl query

Comment: *"but I am unable to get this to work ... having trouble ..."* - this is not a useful problem description. Please describe what you've tried, what your expectations were and what happend instead.

Comment: Unable to get this to work as in bad request. Although I was specifically asking if there was a better way to send the POST request.@SteffenUllrich

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will be sending 23 data points, so I will be looking into your suggestion. @prog-fh

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a byte stream. It is unlikely that a single call to `send()` will be able to send your *entire* HTTP request in a single operation anyway (pay attention to the return value!), so you have to be prepared to call `send()` multiple times if needed.  So you may as well break up your logic to `send()` different pieces of data without having to pre-format them together into a single memory buffer, eg:

```c
int send_all(int sckt, const void *buffer, int bufsize)
{
    const char *ptr = (const char*) buffer;
    while (bufsize > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(sckt, ptr, bufsize, 0);
        if (sent < 0)
            return -1;
        ptr += sent;
        bufsize -= sent;
    }
    return 0;
}

int send_str(int sckt, const char *str)
{
    return send_all(sckt, str, strlen(str));
}

int send_str_v(int sckt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sckt);

    char *str;
    while ((str = va_arg(args, char*)) != NULL) {
        if (send_str(sckt, str) < 0) {
            va_end(args);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

...

char clen[16] = {0};
snprintf(clen, 16, "%d", strlen(PostString));

send_str_v (sckt, "POST ", HTTP_PATH, " HTTP/1.1\r\n", NULL);
send_str_v (sckt, "Host: ", HTTP_HOST, "\r\n", NULL);
send_str   (sckt, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
send_str   (sckt, "Content-type: application/json\r\n");
send_str_v (sckt, "Content-length: ", clen, "\r\n", NULL);
send_str   (sckt, "\r\n");        
send_str   (sckt, PostString);
```

Internally, the TCP socket will buffer and fragment data as needed at the networking layer, so don't worry about it so much at the application layer.